# Import a module and use it in julialang

Tags: julia

Since in http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/modules/ there's no much info about modules, I would like to ask the following.

I want to try two modules via ijulia. Both modules are in my working directory as
name-of-files.jul. I will call them generically module_1.jul and module_2.jul.

module_1.jul uses module_2.jul and I load it with

```
using module_2
```

On ijulia session, if I try

```
using module_1
```

gives an error. I also tried

```
include("module_1.jul")
```

This last sentence, when executed, rises an error because the module_1.jul cannot find
variable "x" that I know is contained in module_1.jul (in this case I "loaded" the module
using include("module2.jul") inside module_1.jul

Comment: There's a bit more info in the [Julia Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Modules_and_packages)

Answer (score 10):

Julias module system assumes some things that aren't necessarily obvious from the documenation at first.

1. Julia files should end with .jl extensions.
2. Julia looks for module files in directories defined in the LOAD_PATH variable.
3. Julia looks for files in those directories in the form ModuleName/src/file.jl

If `using module_1` fails then I'm guessing it's because it's source files fail one of the above criteria.

Comment: But looking at the LOAD_PATH variable I feel it would be a downside, no? Somehow I would like to see a julia program like a fortran or even python code, where you compile the modules and then execute the main program but without adding modules from other programs (as I suspect, the variable LOAD_PATH does).

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. LOAD_PATH is just a variable that tells julia where to look. Nothing gets loaded until you type import, include, or using. It's like your terminals PATH variable. Adding to it doesn't cause anything to get loaded.

Comment: But suppose I'm very enthusiastic and I have a million of modules loaded at the LOAD_PATH variable, and suppose that I could also have modules with the same name, different content, stored at different paths. How link correctly which is the one that I want to use if, as I presume, the LOAD_PATH is searched from left to right?

Comment: This conversation will quickly get unproductive. Julia works a certain way and if your enthusiasm doesn't play well with how julia works then julia will fail for you. But it sounds like you still don't quite understand. LOAD_PATH is just a list of strings. It doesn't "load" anything. It just tells julia where to look when you ask it to load something.

Comment: yeah but pay attention, what julia does when you have two modules with the same name, different content, but in different directory loaded at the env variable? That's the real issue since you mention the LOAD_PATH var and you didn't provide an answer.

Comment: @user2820579, you'll get an error about an ambiguous reference to the module (you can easily test it yourself)

Comment: @user2820579 I understand not wanting to fill a module search path with directories all over your system. I think the solution being recommended here is to not to modify a LOAD_PATH variable in for example your shell startup script, but to modify LOAD_PATH locally on a per-script or per-module basis. i.e. the first line of your script/module is `push!(LOAD_PATH, "/path")`

Comment: Actually yes, that's the solution I found after digging elsewhere for some time now. What is currently working very nice for me are these two statements: `path = readstring(`pwd`)`  `push!(LOAD_PATH, chomp(path))`; which automatically load the path in the current program.

Answer (score 1):

Some time has passed since this question. Recently, Noah_S wrote the solution in the comments of the previous answer; this means that it is a recurrent doubt for people starting to learn the language. For their sake, I will re-write it here Noah_S' answer along with my most novel solution.

I am a mess with the `julia` versions and which commands work with the specific ones, so for older julia versions we have to look for the `\path` and then include in the julia module

```
push!(LOAD_PATH, "/path")
```

In newer versions this can be improved. Forget about looking by hand the path and just do

```
path = readstring(`pwd`)
push!(LOAD_PATH, chomp(path))
```

I hope this can be useful to many julians newcomers.

Comment: in Julia 1.1.0, I couldn't find readstring, but pwd() is a function returning the current working directory.

Comment: Then they make this easier in the newest version!